# Jenkins pipeline store SSH credentials as parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following pipeline code:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

     environment {
        SSH_KEY_PARAMETER  = credentials('SSH_KEY')


        
    }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps{
                script{
                    git credentialsId: 'SSH_KEY_PARAMETER', url: 'git@github.com:SomeUser/PrivateRepo.git', branch: 'main'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output is cloning the repo.
Actual output:

```
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@github.com:SomeUser/PrivateRepo.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:1001)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1242)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1302)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:129)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:97)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress -- git@github.com:SomeUser/PrivateRepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2681)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2102)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:86)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:624)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:999)
```

If I change the pipeline code to use the credential ID instead of the variable it works:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

     environment {
        SSH_KEY_PARAMETER  = credentials('SSH_KEY')



    }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps{
                script{
                    git credentialsId: 'SSH_KEY', url: 'git@github.com:SomeUser/PrivateRepo.git', branch: 'main'
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In my pipeline I need to manage a bunch of SSH keys depending on the environment, so I need to be able to parameterize the SSH key, am I missing something here or is it not possible to assign an SSH key as variable?

Answer (score 1):

Your `environment` directive with use of the `credentials` helper method is syntactically correct. Your syntax for accessing the variable is incorrect. You are assigning a literal string value `'SSH_KEY_PARAMETER'` to the `credentialsId` argument. The actual value also is stored in the `env` object, so you would access it with the appropriate key `env.SSH_KEY_PARAMETER`. The usage would then look like:

```
credentialsId: env.SSH_KEY_PARAMETER
```

However, the `git` step is expecting the credentials ID for that argument and not the actual credentials. Therefore, you need to also assign the value of the `credentialsId` in the `environment` directive instead:

```
SSH_KEY_PARAMETER = 'SSH_KEY'
```

Putting it all together, we have:

```
environment {
  SSH_KEY_PARAMETER  = 'SSH_KEY'
}

stages {
  ...
  git credentialsId: env.SSH_KEY_PARAMETER, url: 'git@github.com:SomeUser/PrivateRepo.git', branch: 'main'
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting `Warning: CredentialId "****" could not be found.`

Comment: @SimpleNiko The credential ID needs to exist and be entered into the plugin.

Comment: It does exist, otherwise it wouldn't have worked when I directly entered `credentialsId: 'SSH_KEY'`

Comment: @SimpleNiko Unfortunately I cannot help you further then, because my answer works if the credential is entered into the plugin with the given name.